# Overriding Firefox's blocking of less-secure https pages

Tags: firefox, https

I recently installed a web filter.  Any time an https site is filtered, I get the error `ssl_error_protocol_version_alert` (`Peer reports incompatible or unsupported protocol version`), or occasionally, `The connection to *** was interrupted while the page was loading.`  I cannot override the web blocker until I know which category this site is blocked under, so I can unblock that category of sites.  However, in order for me to know which category it is blocked under, I first must view this page -- which Firefox is blocking.

In looking up solutions online, I have tried:

- an older version of Firefox, which should have an `I Understand the Risks` button, in order to access this site; but, the button is not there.
- most solutions say to change some `security.tls.***` settings on the `about:config` page -- all the `security.tls` settings are missing altogether (although `security.enable_tls` is there, and set to `true`).
- I have changed `security.ssl.enable_ocsp_must_staple` to `false` and restarted Firefox, but nothing changed.

What other settings can I change, in order to make Firefox show me the webpage despite it not having a "secure enough" certificate?